# Login loop for main and guest account after installing NVIDIA driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia

Yesterday I finished building a new PC with the following:

- I5 processor
- Asus A97-A MB
- EVGA gtx 960

When I first started it yesterday I was still using Ubuntu 12.10. Most everything worked ok except there were some sound issues and the ethernet did not work. I updated to 14.02 LTS today in an attempt to fix those issues (and it did) but it messed up the graphics card drivers (or so it seemed; DOTA was running at 10 FPS.)

I ran through [this set of instructions on Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2263316) to try to fix the graphics card drivers. After completing them I have been stuck in a login loop. When I enter my password the screen goes black and comes right back to the log on screen.

I did `ls -la .Xauthority` and my user name is listed twice like it should be.

Comment: Can you post a link to *"this set of instructions"* that you used, please? Also, how did you update from 12.10 to 14.04?

Comment: Oops sorry. I forgot to relink it.
[link]http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2263316

I upgraded using the updater in ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I re-did the last section of [the instructions I linked to on Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2263316), the part for installing the nVidia driver.

When I did it the first time I used the 340.65 driver. This time I used the newest 346.72 driver and that seemed to fix it. I have no idea why; maybe it was just an issue with that particular driver.

Answer (score 0):

I am only familiar with Kubuntu so this may not help.  At the login screen do not login.  Do Control-Alt-F1.  then login with your username and password.

Now run

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a  
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get -f install
```

this: configures all packages
looks for updates
updates including kernel
looks for dependency issues and installs them.

After that is all done type startx and try to login again.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I ran through all that and it did a bunch of stuff. when I did the startx it went to a black screen with a cursor blinking in the upper left corner. Not sure if that is normal or not. I left it set for awhile but it did not change so I restart it with the power button. I tried to log in again but still the same thing. It kicks me back to the log on screen.