# Ubuntu 14.04.3 going into login loop on Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, login

I tried making a Ubuntu VM using VirtualBox twice already using version 14.04.3 on Windows 10, but both times I am ran into a login loop, where it looks like it will log me in, but does not. This is happening both for my user account and for the guest account. I have looked into some fixes, like this one: [Stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/623854/stuck-in-a-login-loop), [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

but none of the fixes worked (everything with .Xauthority looked fine, rebooting didn't help, etc.)

Do you have any suggestions to fix this problem?

Comment: I tried everything on there, and nothing worked :(

Comment: No, I tried everything on there before I asked this question....

Comment: Look, I'm sorry man, I'm new to this forum, and I edited the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just FYI, I solved this problem by switching to the 64 bit of Linux from the 32 bit. I guess this was a bug confined to the 32 bit version.